# How to operate overload ">>"?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
Product **products;

int numProducts = 0;

void setup()
{
    ifstream finput("products.txt");
    //get # of products first.
    finput >> numProducts;
    products = new Product* [numProducts];

    //get product codes, names & prices.
    for(int i=0; i<numProducts; i++) {
        products[i] = new Product;
        finput >> products[i]->getCode() >> products[i]->getName() >> products[i]->getPrice();
    }
}
```

I am getting an "invalid operands to binary expression" error for this line:

```
finput >> products[i]->getCode() >> products[i]->getName() >> products[i]->getPrice();
```

Do I need to operator overload `>>` and how would I do it?

Comment: You don't absolutely need to overload >>, but that is a reasonable way to solve the issue above. Another way would be to read the values into variables and then use your class setters to set the data members.

Comment: Why so many pointers? `Product **products; products = new Product* [numProducts]; products[i] = new Product;` The code would be easier with one less pointer `Product *products; products = new Product [numProducts];`. There's no reason to use two levels of pointer (there's actually no reason to even use one level, but two is just excessive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a very simple example, assuming a basic definition for `Product` as:

```
class Product
{
   int code;
   string name;
   double price;

public:
   Product(int code, const std::string& name, double price)
      : code{code}, name{name}, price{price}
   {}

   int getCode() const { return code; }
   const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
   double getPrice() const { return price; }
};
```

You can't *read in* using `operator>>` directly into the return values from `getCode()`, `getName()` or `getPrice()`.  Those are for *accessing* those values.

Instead, you need to read in the values and construct products from those values like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numProducts; ++x)
{
   int code = 0;
   string name;
   double price = 0;

   finput >> code >> name >> price;
   products[i] = new Product{code,name,price};
}
```

Now, you could refactor this into `operator>>`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Product& p)
{
   int code = 0;
   string name;
   double price = 0;

   in >> code >> name >> price;
   p = Product{code,name,price};
   return in;
}
```

There are a bunch of other things to consider about this code:

- Use `std::vector<Product>` instead of your own array
- The examples below won't work if `name` has spaces
- There's no error checking and `operator>>` *can* fail

Answer (score 2):

In your Class, write down this function

```
friend ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& in, Product& p1)
{
    in >> p1.code >> p1.name /* ..etc */;

    return in;
}
```