# How would I operate overload "<<"?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

My professor said operator overloading of << is optional here but I wanted to know how I could do it as I was only able to figure it out without using overloading.

This is a function in my code:

```
void listProducts()
{
    //list all the available products.
    cout << "Available products:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<numProducts; i++)
        cout << products[i]->getCode() << ": " << products[i]->getName() << " @ "
             << products[i]->getPrice() << "/pound.\n";
}
```

And this is the product.cpp file:

```
Product :: Product(int code, string name, double price) {
this->code = code;
this->name = name;
this->price = price;
}

int Product:: getCode(){
return code;
}

string Product :: getName(){
return name;
}

double Product :: getPrice(){
return price;
}
```

Comment: The answer is the same as for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61069078/8372853) you posted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out,const classname &outval)
{
    //output operation like out<<outval.code<<":"<<outval.name<<"@"<<outval.price;
    return out;
}
```

and

```
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out,const classname &outval);
```

in your class to access private members.

Answer (score 0):

If you understood the solution to your previous question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069078/how-to-operate-overload), then understanding the below code is very easy. The only difference is the usage of friend function about which you can read [gfg link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/).

For your better understanding, the exact same example is given below,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Product
{
private:
    int code; string name; double price;
public:
    Product(int, string, double);
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Product &p);

};

Product :: Product(int code, string name, double price) {
    this->code = code;
    this->name = name;
    this->price = price;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const Product &p)
{
    out<< p.code << ": " << p.name << " @ "
             << p.price << "/pound.\n";
    return out;
}


int main()
{
   Product book1(1256,"Into to programming", 256.50);
   Product book2(1257,"Into to c++", 230.50);
   cout<<book1<<endl<<book2;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI it is working in my machine and online compilers like ideone.com. I think it should run just fine as we are declaring function using friend function which can access private members of its class.